# how to install the ID3 extension on Windows

Tags: php, id3

using this code:

```
$mp3_tags= id3_get_tag($mp3_file);
printr($mp3_tags);
```

but there is an error of calling undefined function did a search and found out that i had to enable the ID3 extension for PHP and im stuck doing it on windows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The manual [shows how to install and this extension](http://www.php.net/manual/en/id3.setup.php) (and all other standard ones too).

Unfortunately, it is [not available as a compiled DLL on Windows](http://www.php.net/manual/en/id3.installation.php). You can [compile it](http://www.php.net/manual/en/install.windows.building.php) if you wish.